# customer or passenger: man traveling in a taxi

Tags: vocabulary

What do natives in the UK and USA call a person who catches a taxi?

Is that a customer?

OR

Is that a passenger?

Please note that he is  getting services and here is the definition of 'customer:

a person or an organization that buys goods or services from a shop or business

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/customer?q=customer

Answer (score 1):

He is both a customer and a passenger.

Using "customer" emphasises the fact that "the customer is always right" so is used by taxi companies to remind their drivers to have a "customer focus".  Passenger emphasises the fact that he is getting a service from the driver.

So we have "Taxi passenger rules: No smoking, do not disturb driver etc."  But "Taxi customer care number (to call if you have a complaint about a taxi)"

Comment: There is also (Wiktionary) fare : A paying passenger, especially in a taxi.